# Spark AR Trouble setting up timer

Tags: time, filter, timer, instagram, spark-ar-studio

I’m trying to create a visible timer on my Spark Ar but couldn’t find the necessary information to start off. Does anyone have any tips? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use the Time Module in the script to create a Timer

```
const TimeModule = require('Time');
const Scene = require('Scene');

const mySceneObject = Scene.root.find('mySceneObject');

var yourTime = null;
var count = 0;

yourTimer = TimeModule.setInterval(function()
{
if(count == 10)
{
 //do something here
mySceneObject.transform.scaleY = 10;
}
count++;
},timeValueInMilliSeconds);
```